# Spring Autowiring - if object name needs to be same as beanId always?

Tags: java, spring

I have defined bean in spring configuration something like -

```
<bean id="xyz" class="com.foo.Test">
```

and the class where I am using the bean is

```
package com.bar;
import com.foo.Test;

Class Demo {
      @Autowired
      Test xyz;

      //Do operations of Test using abc now

}
```

what I am asking I tried below and it worked fine.

```
package com.bar;
import com.foo.Test;

Class Demo {
     @Autowired
     Test abc;

     //Do operations of Test using abc now

}
```

So if keeping the bean id same as object name doesn't matter ?

Thanks.

Comment: `@Autowired` works on type not on name... It will only use the name of the variable as last resort. So it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you autowire a bean and the spring context defines exactly *one* bean which is assignment compatible with the type you wire the bean to (in your case `Test`) then spring does not require any additional information.

If the spring context does define more than one bean which is assignment compatible with the type you wire the bean to you have to add the annotation `@Qualifier` and specify the identifier like this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("xyz")
Test abc;
```

*Spring Framework Reference Documentation:*

- [@Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation)
- [@Qualifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

Comment: can you provide reference doc for this ?